# java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0c0000be:ASN.1 encoding routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_TAG

Tags: java, android, rsa, x509certificate, sha

Here I am trying to verify the signature against the pass file which I have.

I have created a method to validate the signature as below. Which have context data (.pass file bytes and signature bytes)

**Signature hash algorithm is RSA with SHA512 and PKCS1 padding, Do I need to specify anything for PKS1 padding?**

```
public boolean validateSignature(Context context, byte[] data, byte[] signature) {
        try {
            // Reading public certificate from raw folder
            InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.public_cer);

            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

            // This line is giving error
            X509Certificate crt = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(is);

            PublicKey publicKey = crt.getPublicKey();

            Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA512withRSA");
            sig.initVerify(publicKey);
            sig.update(data);

            return sig.verify(Base64.decode(signature, Base64.NO_WRAP));
        } catch (Exception ex) {

             Log.d(TAG, ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        return false;
    }
```

I am trying to verifying the signature with below code but getting error.

```
        if (validateSignature(
                applicationContext,
                bytes, // Byte array of Data file
                signatureBytes // Byte array of signature file
            )
        ) {
            Log.d(TAG, "checkSignature: true")
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "checkSignature: false")
        }
```

Error

com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory$ParsingException: java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0c0000be:ASN.1 encoding routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_TAG

I am trying to verify the signature against the given public.cer file

I the signature is verified I can confirm that the file is authenticated to use.

My Targeted sdk is 32

Comment: The code does not seem to be the problem, but rather the certificate. It may not be a certificate, it may be in the wrong format/encoding, or it may be corrupted somehow. As a result, the import fails.

Comment: I doubt that the same certificate works on the server side. I check that twice.